# Running selenium code with junit and jmeter

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I create jar file from my selenium code , my code is to test web site so i surround with junit, now I am trying to run this with jmeter and i get the next error :

> 2016/01/17 11:06:19 WARN -
>   jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Missing jar? Could not create com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.gui.WebDriverSamplerGui.
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jsyntaxpane/DefaultSyntaxKit
>   2016/01/17 11:06:19 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering
>   JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22 
>   2016/01/17 11:06:19 INFO  -
>   jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className
>   property for htmlParser, using default  2016/01/17 11:06:19 INFO  -
>   jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is 
>   2016/01/17 11:06:19 INFO  -
>   jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for
>   application/xhtml+xml is   2016/01/17 11:06:19 INFO  -
>   jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for
>   application/xml is   2016/01/17 11:06:19 INFO  -
>   jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is
>   2016/01/17 11:06:19 INFO  -
>   jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for
>   text/vnd.wap.wml is
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser  2016/01/17
>   11:06:19 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.WebServiceSamplerGui 
>   2016/01/17 11:06:19 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.modifier.gui.ParamModifierGui 
>   2016/01/17 11:06:19 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found
>   at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\keytool'  2016/01/17
>   11:06:19 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test
>   Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd
>   party resources in file
>   C:\Users\orela\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\proxyserver.jks
>   2016/01/17 11:06:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample
>   TimeStamps are START times  2016/01/17 11:06:23 INFO  -
>   jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to
>   ISO-8859-1  2016/01/17 11:06:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult:
>   sampleresult.useNanoTime=true  2016/01/17 11:06:23 INFO  -
>   jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
>   2016/01/17 11:06:33 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Problem
>   retrieving gui java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getTestElementCheckSum(GuiPackage.java:853)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentNode(GuiPackage.java:435)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getCurrentGui(GuiPackage.java:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbHnR.png)

Comment: Please add your code, the error is NullPointerException which means you are trying to do something with null object.

Comment: Additionally you should check if you could get jsyntaxpane/DefaultSyntaxKit onto the class path

Comment: The code is working fine in intellij\eclips ,the error is only when runing in jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

have you added the selenium-->libs (copy all the jars in the libs) into jmeter/lib and also in the jmeter/lib/ext (and delete the duplicate old versions of jars)

Comment: Yes i added the jars

Answer (score 0):

First you have an issue with your setup as some jar is missing:

> jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Missing jar? Could not create com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.gui.WebDriverSamplerGui. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jsyntaxpane/DefaultSyntaxKit

This one ? :

> https://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/

But you are also facing a bug fixed in nightly build:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58795

Try using nightly build and fix the first issue:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

> Installing JMeter runtime
>   Download the _bin and _lib files
>   Unpack the archives into the same directory structure
>   The other archives are not needed to run JMeter.

Comment: Hi @UBIK LOAD PACK, I did not understand your answer can u please give me some more detail